# MVC @RenderSection "sections have been defined but have not been rendered" scripts. When multiple levels of page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with MVC v4.
I have a '_BootstrapLayout' page which defines all the twitter bootstrap etc stuff, A main page which defines the site layout, navbar etc, and site pages which inherit from main page.

> _BootstrapLayout.cshtml
>
> _MainPage.cshtml @{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_BootstrapLayout.cshtml"; }
>
> Index.cshtml @{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainPage.cshtml";}

So
Master Page --> Main Page --> site Page(s)

The _BootstrapLayout page contains a rendersection for scripts

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

I want to add a scripts section to the Index.cshtml page, but when I do I get the exception

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
...

        });

    </script>
}
```

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered
> for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_MainPage.cshtml": "scripts".

So I added an empty @section scripts to the _MainPage.cshtml, still the same problem ?
Even if I add code to the _MainPage scripts section I still get the same error.  It doesn't matter where I put the @section in _MainPage, still get the same error.

If I purposely don't close the section (ie, delete the }) then I get an error which indicates that the section is incorrect, so it's parsing the section in _MainPage.

How can I get @RenderSections for scripts on the site pages to work in this case ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You'll need to redefine the section in `_MainPage.cshtml`.

_BootstrapLayout.cshtml

```
@RenderSection("scripts", false)
```

_MainPage.cshtml

```
@section scripts
{
   @RenderSection("scripts", false)
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@section scripts
{
   <script>
     // etc.
   </script>
}
```

Comment: Excellent ! - Thank you so much. I'd never have guessed this.  I've searched around and found several reports of this and none of them give this as an answer.