# Conditional section in MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a twin Layout setup that renders either the entire page (with navigation) or just the contents depending on whether it was an Ajax request or not.  I achieve this like so:

*_LayoutRightPanel.cshtml*

```
@{
    Layout = !Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" : null;
}
```

This works fine for most pages, but pages that are requested via Ajax that contains `@section{}`s dont work (they do when loaded normally).  I get the following error:

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered
>   for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutRightPanel.cshtml":
>   "scripts".

At the bottom of my _LayoutRightPanel I do the following to render scripts, either forcing the section to render on the main layout or rendering it on the current page if its an ajax request

```
@if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    RenderSection("scripts", false);
}
else{
    @section scripts{
        @RenderSection("scripts", false)
    }
}
```

Comment: When you update the portion page by Ajax, why not put the script in the partial view loaded instead of changing the entire layout.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@section scripts{
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
}
```

Why are you rendering the `scripts` section **inside of** the `scripts` section? I don't see how that can end in any way but errors or infinite recursion (which ends in an error).

**Edit** *This is incorrect. See my update below.*

`RenderSection()` should be used on the _Layout page (or any page that is wrapped around the current view). This is the **target location** (where you want the section to end up)

`@section scripts{}` should be used on your (Partial)View. This is the **source location** (where you define the section's contents).

Having both references to the same section on the same page defeats the purpose of why you should be using sections in the first place (to pass certain HTML parts to other, wrapping views (e.g. _Layout.cshtml))

*Slight update*
To directly answer your question, I think the error is thrown because the  `RenderSection` call that's inside of the `@section` cannot find any section called "scripts" because it has not yet been defined (you're in the process of defining it).

**Update**

[According to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479442/mvc-rendersection-sections-have-been-defined-but-have-not-been-rendered-scrip), duplicate names should not be an issue (so you can disregard my comment below).

However, the root cause of the issue (in that question) was that the script sections weren't chained (i.e. you can't render the section 2 layout pages up, it has to be in the specific Layout page of your view (and then keep chaining it upwards to the next Layout page).

Can you confirm that to be set up as intended?

*Maybe offtopic, but is there any added value to passing the scripts section to the upper Layout page? Since you're going to render the section either way, should it not work if you always place it in the _LayoutRightPanel page?*

Comment: Bear in mind I have two nested layout pages.  The first one, if its part of a full page request, simply farms off the script rendering to its parent layout.  If its an AJAX request itll try render the script section itself

Comment: Try using different names for the script sections. Things that work 'stringly typed' generally do not work if you start using duplicate names. There should never be a case where you both set and render the same section in the same page document.

Comment: @Chris: Duplicate names are not an issue. I updated my answer.

Comment: This is true, you cannot render 2 chains up, unless you do it via the method I use (i.e. render the scripts within another section).  This is how I've seen it done in other SO questions.  I suppose I could just render it there and not worry about it further, it is usually better for rendering performance if you render scripts last.  But I doubt in this case it'll matter